# Procs and Lambdas for what when we have methods

Tags: ruby

My doubt is pretty much a matter of misunderstanding...

From what I read, a `block` is a group of code enclosed by `{}` or `do` and `end`.

From my understanding, what a `Proc` or `Lambda` does is:

1. Get this `block`
2. Assign the `block` to a `variable`

Which means; we don't need to repeat the whole `block` all the time.

But, what is the difference among a `Proc`, `Lambda` and a standard `Method`? From my understanding, they all work the same way.

Comment: read this - http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2006/04/18/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-methods/

Comment: Thanks @Cary, but in fact I do understand Procs and Lambdas. What I am asking is simply Why to use them instead of using a method. Doesn't it do exactly the same thing?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly it might have been better to  have framed it something like this: "I understand the differences among Procs, Lambdas and methods, but I don't understand when it is appropriate to use one rather each of the other two, considering that they all do pretty much the same thing. Are there guidelines that would help me understand that?".

Answer (score 1):

There is one crucial difference between `Proc`s (and lambdas) and methods. `Proc`s are objects, methods aren't. And since Ruby is an object-oriented language, where you can only do things with and to objects, that is *very* important.

So, if you want to pass a piece of code to a method, you need to have an object, and that's what `Proc`s provide.

You *can* get a proxy object that represents a method via the `Object#method` method, which will return an instance of the `Method` class (which duck-types `Proc`).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in ruby is considered an object. `Proc` and `lambda` are fundamentally similar constructs. This topic is highly opinionated as far as usage goes.

The key advantages is that they can be easily passed around into other `blocks` and the syntax is short and sweet. Consider the following very simple examples:

```
multiply = Proc.new {|x,y| x*y}
subtract = lambda {|x,y| x-y}
add      = ->(x,y) {x+y}

def do_math (opr, *b) 
  opr.each do |bloc|
    puts bloc.call(b[0],b[1])
  end
end

do_math([multiply, subtract, add], 10, 5)
 # => 50
 # => 5
 # => 15

puts multiply.call(5,5)
 # => 25
puts subtract.call(5,5)
 # => 0
puts add.call(5,5)
 # => 10
```

To get a better grasp of what they are, watch this video: [An Introduction to Procs, Lambdas and Closures in Ruby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBC-G6hahWA)

Additionally the documentation has more examples here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html

Comment: Gosh I find that thin arrow syntax ugly. Can anyone explain the logic and beauty I'm not seeing behind that?

Comment: @kal, beauty is the eye of the beholder. You're entitled to think that. I personally like and appreciate the brevity. I know what it does and its only two characters. `->` I also prefer `<<` to writing `.push`

Comment: I prefer `<<` to `#push` too. But here it just looks strangely out of place, and also puts the arguments outside the block. The whole thing just looks wrong to me, but I thought maybe I'm missing something. I guess I'll just stick with `lambda`.

Comment: @Kal I know what you're saying. But it's all about perspective. Think of it as it's stabbing the `block` with the `arguments`, hence `stabby lambda`. :)

Comment: I remember reading some years ago (in _Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby_ perhaps?) to think of the vertical bars as being a chute through which the arguments slide down and into the block. Somehow that still works for me better than Stabby the lambda! But I digress, which is something I believe one is not supposed to do in these comments. :-)

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog they're all closures. In fact ruby has four types: `Blocks`, `Procs`, `Lambdas` and `Methods`.

Comment: feed, in case you didn't know, you could have just used '@Fred'.  See point #3 of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @cs Thanks I didn't know about the "matching". According to that answer. You should be notified :) Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I found that this [Codecademy section](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-L3ZCI/2/3?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb) helps with the distinction.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually post an answer. Linking to someone else's answer without at least summarizing it in your own is frowned upon.